# Gradle custom Type : Default Task "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, gradle

I want to create a SimpleTask Gradle with JAVA. However I cannot compile my projet because "import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask' is not found.
GradleVersion : 6.3

As said on documentation I create a class on root/buildSrc/src/main/java/SimpleTask.java

With this code I have an :  "error: cannot find symbol" symbol: class DefaultTask.

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;

public class SimpleTask extends DefaultTask {

}
```

I've tried to add the dependency (but same effect)

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gradle/api
    implementation group: 'org.gradle', name: 'api', version: '1.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good tutorial here : https://www.jrebel.com/blog/using-buildsrc-custom-logic-gradle-builds

My problem was that I defined a "source root" with intelliJ in buildSrc. And it causes compilation error.

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with that dependency, but if it exists, it is for Gradle 1.0 from five years ago. That is definitely not what you want.

I don't believe the official Gradle API is published as a dependency. But you can declare a dependency on the API of the current version of Gradle by using the [DependencyHandler.gradleApi()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler:gradleApi()) method like this:

```
dependencies {
   implementation gradleApi()
}
```

Comment: Actualy I'm using now the 6.5.1, and the dependency is implicit if you are in buildSrc. My problem was that I do not used the gradle java plugin in intelliJ so it do not take it automaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the dependency is not necessary.
Actually I have update intelliJ and and the gradle/java plugin. When intelliJ scan a buildSrc/src/main/java directory it transform the directory as a source folder. and compilation are ok.